# Exceptions in the base.h when I run my winui 3 desktop project

Tags: xaml, c++-winrt, winui-3

I get some strange exceptions when I run my winui 3, c++/winrt project. I get three of them that I can press f5 to continue through in debug mode and my code runs as normal, but I can not. The issue is that I do not know what part of my code is causing it. The exceptions are in the base.h file. I have not been able to find anything about what may be causing them. Here is the copied exceptions:

Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFCF3784F69 in Sentinel3.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: winrt::hresult_wrong_thread at memory location 0x00000068E818E688.

The exception above popped up in the debugger when result == impl::error_not_implemented  in the base.h file. From what I found online that means that the Hresult is throwing a E_NOTIMPL HRESULT error meaning something is not implemented correctly but I cannot tell what that is.

Exception thrown at 0x00007FFCF3784F69 in Sentinel3.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: winrt::hresult_error at memory location 0x00000068E818E8C8.

This exception above popped up in the debugger after the [[noreturn]] inline WINRT_IMPL_NOINLINE void throw_hresult(hresult const result)   function in the base.h file

Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFCF3784F69 in Sentinel3.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: winrt::hresult_error at memory location 0x00000068E818E8C8.

This exception above also popped up in the debugger after the [[noreturn]] inline WINRT_IMPL_NOINLINE void throw_hresult(hresult const result)   function in the base.h file

Edit:: So I figured out that I needed to update something in the debugger for visual studio, and now know that the problem is "-        result  RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.  winrt::hresult"  I am still not sure what part of my code is causing the problem, I assume it is something to do with updating the UI within the MainWindow.xaml.cpp file, but I am not sure what part is causing it. I found some stuff online about using something like adispatcher.invoke() function to update the UI but it seems to only be available in c# or at least I could not find an example of it with c++.

Comment: C++/WinRT maps asynchronous operations onto C++20 coroutines. While you *can* manually schedule work to run on an arbitrary thread (e.g. [`CoreDispatcher::RunAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync)) C++/WinRT provides far more convenient access (such as [`resume_foreground`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/resume-foreground)). See [Advanced concurrency and asynchrony with C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency-2) for detailed information.